# Javascript malfunction, not redirecting right

Tags: javascript

I set "wa, or and id" (visitors from these states) to be redirected to website1.com - and when I visited the website, it redirected me to website1.com (so it knows I'm in WA). But if I change wa to fl, then visit the site, it redirects me to google.com - the default URL I set.

In the above example, if they're not from wa, id or or - they should stay on the page/not be redirected (unless there's a legitimate query error, which this does't seem to be, since it knows I'm in WA)

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thank you

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

calling another JS file with this contents:

```
var redirect = (function () {
    /* This implements the actual redirection. */
    var redirectBrowser = function (site) {
      // Enter default URL below
      var uri = "http://www.google.com/?=error";

      if(site != "default") {
        switch (site)
        {
          // For each site put the iso_code identfiers for each state/province (in lowercase) you want to redirect after each case. Copy and paste as below for more options.
           case "fl":
           case "or":
           case "id": 
               uri = "http://www.website1.com";


        }
      }

        window.location = uri;
    };

    var onSuccess = function (geoipResponse) {
        /* There's no guarantee that a successful response object
         * has any particular property, so we need to code defensively. */
        if (!geoipResponse.subdivisions[0].iso_code) {
            redirectBrowser("default");
            return;
        }

        /* ISO country codes are in upper case. */
        var code = geoipResponse.subdivisions[0].iso_code.toLowerCase();
        if ( code ) {
            redirectBrowser(code);
        }
        else {
            redirectBrowser("default");
        }
    };

    /* We don't really care what the error is, we'll send them
     * to the default site. */
    var onError = function (error) {
        redirectBrowser("default");
    };

    return function () {
        geoip2.city( onSuccess, onError );
    };
}());

redirect();
```

Answer (score 1):

change your switch statement to this and see if it works:

```
switch (site){
    case "fl":
    case "or":
    case "id":{ 
        uri = "http://www.website1.com";break;}
    default:
        return;   
 }
```

Comment: @user1446650 happy to help :) . why dont you accept the answer?is there any other problem?